# Merging two array of objects with foreign key id

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am making 2 api calls to receive two sets of data.

```
const callOne = await api('GET', `${baseUrl}callOne`);
const callTwo = await api('GET', `${baseUrl}callTwo`);
```

I can then output the results

```
console.log(callOne.data);
console.log(callTwo.data);
```

So resultOne is an array of objects.  I am showing a couple of the objects below.

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Some Name",
      "description":"Some description",
      "currency":"USD",
      "price":"350",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Some Name",
      "description":"Some description",
      "currency":"USD",
      "price":"12",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
]
```

It is pretty much the same with resultTwo.  Just showing a few results here.

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "resultOneId":1,
      "startDate":"2022-02-01T16:00:00.000Z",
      "endDate":"2022-02-08T18:00:00.000Z",
      "duration":"3 minutes",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "resultOneId":1,
      "startDate":"2021-02-08T09:00:00.000Z",
      "endDate":"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
      "duration":"2 hours",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
    {
      "id":3,
      "resultOneId":2,
      "startDate":"2021-02-08T09:00:00.000Z",
      "endDate":"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
      "duration":"5 hours",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
]
```

What I am trying to do is create a new array of Objects, that essentially joins resultTwo with resultOne based on the resultOneId.  So I would imaging ending up with something like this

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Some Name",
      "description":"Some description",
      "currency":"USD",
      "price":"350",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
      "resultTwos": [
          {
              "id":1,
              "resultOneId":1,
              "startDate":"2022-02-01T16:00:00.000Z",
              "endDate":"2022-02-08T18:00:00.000Z",
              "duration":"3 minutes",
              "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
           },
           {
              "id":2,
              "resultOneId":1,
              "startDate":"2021-02-08T09:00:00.000Z",
              "endDate":"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
              "duration":"2 hours",
              "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
           },
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Some Name",
      "description":"Some description",
      "currency":"USD",
      "price":"12",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
      "resultTwos": [
            {
              "id":3,
              "resultOneId":2,
              "startDate":"2021-02-08T09:00:00.000Z",
              "endDate":"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
              "duration":"5 hours",
              "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
           },
      ]
   },
]
```

I have been trying to attempt this using reduce and map but not got very far.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something as simple as:

```
resultOnes.map( one => {return { ...one, resultTwos: resultTwos.filter(two => two.resultOneId === one.id)}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to handle it on server side, but here is the code:

```
const results = []
for (const itemOne of callOne.data) {
    const resultTwos = callTwo.data.filter((itemTwo) =>
        itemTwo.resultOneId == itemOne.data.id
    )
    results.push({ ...itemOne, resultTwos })
}
console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the first array of data and check if they are existing items in the second array of data which has `resultOneId` equal to their `id`

```js
let data1 = [
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Some Name",
      "description":"Some description",
      "currency":"USD",
      "price":"350",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Some Name",
      "description":"Some description",
      "currency":"USD",
      "price":"12",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
];

let data2 = [
   {
      "id":1,
      "resultOneId":1,
      "startDate":"2022-02-01T16:00:00.000Z",
      "endDate":"2022-02-08T18:00:00.000Z",
      "duration":"3 minutes",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "resultOneId":1,
      "startDate":"2021-02-08T09:00:00.000Z",
      "endDate":"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
      "duration":"2 hours",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
    {
      "id":3,
      "resultOneId":2,
      "startDate":"2021-02-08T09:00:00.000Z",
      "endDate":"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
      "duration":"5 hours",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
];

let result = data1.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  let items = data2.filter(item => {
    return item.resultOneId === current.id;
  });
  return accumulator.concat({
    ...current, 
    resultTwos: items
  });
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data:any[] = [];

callOne.data.forEach((call1=>any) => {

    const item:any = call1;

    item.resultTwos = callTwo.data.filter((call2:any) => call1.id === call2.resultOneId);

    data.push(item);

})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: you could improve your answer by writing some text for explanation

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

````
var callOne =
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Some Name",
      "description":"Some description",
      "currency":"USD",
      "price":"350",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Some Name",
      "description":"Some description",
      "currency":"USD",
      "price":"12",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
];

var callTwo = 
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "resultOneId":1,
      "startDate":"2022-02-01T16:00:00.000Z",
      "endDate":"2022-02-08T18:00:00.000Z",
      "duration":"3 minutes",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "resultOneId":1,
      "startDate":"2021-02-08T09:00:00.000Z",
      "endDate":"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
      "duration":"2 hours",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   },
    {
      "id":3,
      "resultOneId":2,
      "startDate":"2021-02-08T09:00:00.000Z",
      "endDate":"2021-02-17T18:00:00.000Z",
      "duration":"5 hours",
      "created_at":"2021-12-08T17:53:12.000Z",
   }
];

for(let i=0;i<callOne.length;i++){ //Loops through callOne data
    var id = callOne[i]['id']; //Get id for callOne data
    callOne[i]['resultsTwos'] = []; //create array for callTwo related data
    for(let ii=0;ii<callTwo.length;ii++){ //Loops through calltwo data
        if(callTwo[ii]['resultOneId']!=id) //continue loop if calltwo data is not related to call one data
            continue;
        callOne[i]['resultsTwos'].push(callTwo.data[ii]); //insert calltwo data into callone resultsTwo array
    }
}```
````